# Customise ng serve to proxy calls to /api?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, webpack-dev-server

I created a new application with ng CLI, works like a charm:

`ng new babysteps
cd babysteps
ng serve`

ng serve uses webpack to assemble the app. To fully test it, I need to serve `/api...` from my API mock server (specifically the POST requests). How can I customise the web server used, to redirect that one URL pattern?

The Webpack dev server has [a proxy setting](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html), but it seems (?) `ng serve` doesn't have a config file (or I didn't get).

Do I need to create a `webpack.config.js` or create/edit some other file to proxy ?

Comment: I believe what you are asking for is the proxy configuration. Take a look at [this part of the Angular-CLI documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md).

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can indeed setup a proxy to backend with the angular cli, with the `--proxy-config` flag.

Here is more or less a copy-paste from the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/d22e9ae73763923980fc1e59cfb2a0bf255b98d8/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md):

> Say we have a server running on http://localhost:3000/api and we want
>   all calls to http://localhost:4200/api to go to that server.
>
> We create a file next to projects `package.json` called `proxy.conf.json`
>   with the content
>
> ```
> {
>     "/api":
>     {
>         "target": "http://localhost:3000",
>         "secure": false
>     } 
> }
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> and then we edit the `package.json` file's start script to be
>
> ```
> "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
> ```
>
> and run it with `npm start`

Comment: or if you are running an express backend and webpack build, concurrently run the backend with watch, and the front end with ng serve... "dev": "concurrently \"ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json\" \"webpack --watch\" \"nodemon dist/server/app.bundle.js\""

Comment: @@Michael Dausmann@@ Thanx a lot. I'm struggling for the past few days to setup this. Excellent tip.

Comment: @MichaelDausmann i've been trying to look at how to watch files with proxy conf. I think you answered what ive been looking for but, however I didnt understand your comment :(. Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: @JoshuaJLIVEWilliams concurrently (https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently)is used to run 2 things at once. 
 the first bit is as per the accepted answer, the second bit is from webpack (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/)

Comment: for apis served from Azure, "changeOrigin":true is needed. See https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/424#issuecomment-333452471

Comment: You can even rewrite the URL if you need to. Just add    "pathRewrite": { "^/api": "" }     as the third property beneath "secure" and requests to http://localhost:4200/api will be rewriten to http://localhost:3000 (instead of http://localhost:3000/api) @see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy