# Spring boot redirect angular 5 CORS problem

Tags: javascript, java, spring, angular, spring-boot

I have an angular 5 app that makes a POST request my Spring Boot server. What is done in my backend is simply doing a redirection to another location of my angular application.(I am doing this because I am simulating the redirection that I must perform when an external service makes a POST request to my backend) but when from my angular application I make the post request to my backend to perform the redirection a problem occurs:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://localhost:4200/payment_resume?state=1&billNumber=234343&description=descr&value=120.000&method=Visa'
>   (redirected from 'http://localhost:8083/v1/redirect') from origin
>   'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field
>   Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in
>   preflight response.

what I do not understand is why there is a problem with CORS, if I made the debug in backend and the request is accepted and handled by my server giving a redirect response ... when my backend responds with the redirection in my angular application the error appears...

**Backend code:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional
    public void returnData(UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder, final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        String transactionState="1";
        String billCode="234343";
        String description="descr";
        String billValue="120.000";
        String paymentMethod="Visa";


        response.sendRedirect(hostname+"/payment_resume?state="+ transactionState
                +"&"+"billNumber="+billCode
                +"&"+"description="+description
                +"&"+"value="+billValue
                +"&"+"method="+paymentMethod);
        return;
    }
```

**CORS Configuration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST","PUT","PATCH","DELETE","OPTIONS"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

**Frontend code:**

```
redirect(){
    this.http.post(environment.apiUrlBase+"/redirect","").subscribe();
  }
```

my question is what configuration should I do in my angular application so that this can work?

Many Thanks!

Comment: to conter CORS effect in my projects, I used a proxy when I run the Angular server. Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42219277/customise-ng-serve-to-proxy-calls-to-api) to another Stack Overflow post. It will probably miss a line in the config. I added : `"changeOrigin": true`. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue and then I used **CrosFilter**. Add below **Bean** and try

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("HEAD");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

Comment: I replaced the configuration I had for which you suggested, but it did not work..